# Get rid of an old application icon on new Android

Tags: android, icons

Some time ago I made a simple Android application - a shared intent handler that uploads data.

Now I designed a new SVG-icon for it, imported in project as vector graphic, then converted with InkScape to a series of PNGs and replaced all the PNGs in the project.

The application is now shown with the new icon on

- Android 4.3 (SGS3, Stock firmware)
- and Android 7.1 (SGS2, LineageOS)

but Android 11 (API level 30, Samsung Galaxy A50, stock firmware) shows still the old icon.

**There are no more places left in application where the default icon (green android head with ears) could reside!!!**

May be the default icon is shown when some expected resource is simply missing?

I replaced image with the new one in following files:

- app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher_round.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher_round.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png
- app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png

I noticed that there is no `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` in `app\src\main\res\drawable\` folder, only in `app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\`. Is this normal?

My `app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

and when I Ctrl-click on `@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground` in Android Studio, it leads me to `app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml`.

When I change @drawable to @mipmap a default icon is still there.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the phone?

Comment: Of course. I restarted it many-many times. Also Android 8 device where the app was never installed before, showed the old (or default?) icon.

Comment: Ok, sorry for suggesting the obvious but icons issues are sometimes magically resolved by a restart, so I had to ask :)

Comment: Just now I deleted the application, turned the phone off/on and launched USB debugging on the phone from Android Studio. The app is still with the old icon on Android 11, API level 30.

Comment: in the manifest, what entry do you have under `android:roundIcon` and `android:icon`?

Comment: android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"

Comment: which logo or image do you see when you open `@drawable/ic_launcher_background` and `@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground` file.

Comment: in `app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml` how it's look

Comment: When I Ctrl-click on `@drawable/ic_launcher_background`, the file `app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_background.xml` is opened and it contains what it should - nothing (transparent background). When I Ctrl-click on `@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground`, the file `app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml` is opened and the right icon is in there.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding icons from

res -> drawable -> right click -> new -> add image asset -> launcher icon

Change your launcher icon there and it should be visible properly and everywhere.

Comment: Sorry: `add image asset -> launcher icon` - where is it? `Icon type` = `Launcher iconS (adaptive and legacy)`? These ones? I already did it, with no better effect than manual replacing.

Comment: Yes, You should add from res -> drawable and then right click on drawable folder and then follow the path given above and in the last it will ask for png image and you need to upload that.

Comment: I already did it. The default icon was still there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just undo what you did when replacing all of the PNGs.

You should follow this image that I posted for you.

Using this Image Asset took you can simple create App Launchers icons for legacy and latest versions.